# References insert non-English caption label in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting Microsoft Word completely to another language](https://superuser.com/questions/288529/setting-microsoft-word-completely-to-another-language)

I have English and Chinese language installed on my computer, but when I try to insert a caption, I got three labels – they seem to be in German.

I wonder why I am getting them… I have Ginger and Mendeley add-ins, and don't know if they cause this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the add-ins to see if it remedies the issue?

Comment: This dupe closing is incorrect. The answer is the dupe does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check to ensure English is the default language set for Office and Windows.

> File -> Options -> Language

If this isn't working: change Windows Language to the wrong one and change it back to English (works only for Windows 7 Prof. and above).

Comment: It is weird, English is there , I removed the other language and instead of 3 lables I got 6 ! I removed the 3 german labels !