# Convert Word 2010 document labels from German to English?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, language

A German colleague of mine sent me a Word document to edit in Word 2010.
When I try to label a figure, the label options I'm presented are:

- Abbildung
- Formel
- Tabelle

How do I tell Word to present me options in English?

If I start a new document, the options are presented in English, so I don't believe there is a system-wide issue here. Below is a screenshot of my language preferences, obtained from *Review tab → Language → Language Preferences...*

[image: language preferences]

Looks quite healthy to me. Any ideas how I can solve this issue?

*There is a [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/460039/references-insert-non-english-caption-label-in-word-2010), but I don't think it applies to me as I'm only affected in one document, whereas the OPs in those questions have a systemic issue.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the document open, go into the VB Editor and create the following Sub. You may need to select the Normal template and use Insert->Module to create somewhere where you can paste the code. Substitute the language/version ID you really want. If it isn't wdEnglishUS, you can delete the "= wdEnglishUS", and start retyping. When you type the `=`, the VB Editor should present the list.

```
Sub changeLanguage()
    ActiveDocument.Content.LanguageID = wdEnglishUS
End Sub
```

Run the code by pressing F5. That should switch any new captions to the English language ones you want. The problem is that no such change will modify the existing captions. For that, you will need to do a find/replace. The caption names are used in several places:

- the captions themselves
- the { SEQ } fields used to insert the caption sequence number. Make
  sure you use Alt-F9 to display these field codes before doing any find/replace
- any { TOC } field in the document used to insert a list of Figures

In addition...
Word does not appear to update the text of the field result when you specify "above/below", even when you have changed the Primary Editing Language to the one you want. The following piece of VBA attempts to replace all REF fields in an effort to get Word to modify those results. It hasn't been tested much.

```
Sub replaceRefFields()
Dim f As Word.Field
Dim l As Long
Dim r As Word.Range
Dim s As String
With ActiveDocument
  For l = .Fields.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Fields(l)
      If .Type = wdFieldRef Then
        Set r = .Result
        s = .Code
        .Delete
        r.Fields.Add r, wdFieldEmpty, s, False
        Set r = Nothing
      End If
    End With
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm the language change works as expected. I've got few enough existing "Figure" labels that I can change those by hand.

Comment: Interestingly - I've discovered it doesn't adjust the text for the "Above/Below" option that can be inserted.

Comment: I can see the problem, and AFAICS the fields have to be replaced. But I've had problems trying to update my Answer with some VBA for that - will try again tomorrow.

Comment: Now added, and the introductory text modified. FWIW, not having to explain how to enter a complete Sub (or link to an explanation) is why I often suggest use of Immediate Mode. But it's "Swings and roundabouts," really :-)